# Detecting when a liquid passes through a 12 inch diameter hole

Tags: sensor

I'm trying to detect when a thin stream of liquid or rapid series of droplets pass through a hole of approximately 12 inches in diameter. Basically, trying to detect when a stream of urine passes through a toilet seat.

I was thinking of possibly using some sort of IR or ultrasonic sensor array or possibly a rapid scan system a la supermarket barcode scanner. However, I think that these will be difficult too build, too bulky, or too expensive.

Any other more elegant solutions?

Comment: do you need to differentiating between a stream and body parts?

Comment: how about a microphone? or a hydrophone?

Comment: Welcome!  Are you wanting to measure the stream or do something like timing or flush-when-finished?

Comment: why wouldn't you lift the seat?

Comment: @jsotola it is to detect when someone doesn't lift the seat.

Comment: @COLWotohice your post is an XY question ... asking about your solution to a problem instead of asking about the problem ... your comment should have been included in your question right from the start

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The water in the sifon is electrically isolated until some urine is added. If you attach a capacitive sensor close to the water in the sifon, you can see a significant increase in capacitance, >5 pF in my experience. Do not use absolute values, just detect rapid positive changes within some seconds. Such a system is blind for a while (up to 60 s) after a flush, until the water film on the surfaces has evaporated.

You can detect an added volume of 20 ml, because the salt in the urine changes conductivity in the sifon, what helps. 100 Hz sampling rate with averager and filter were enough for my setup.

A drawback is, that the sensor also triggers if someone slams the door and the water in the sifon swings according to the air pressure change.

Here is a typical sensor signal with urine detection in yellow followed by a flush in blue:

[image: Sifon Sensor Signal]

The yellow values sometimes begin to drop if the contact to the human body is lost.

This is a small volume example with a critical low sensor area:

[image: MinimumVolumeAdded]

Comment: +1 "In my experience ..." --> massmind at work

Comment: What is a "sifon"? Are you referring to the toilet bowel? Something else?

Comment: if the user is german it looks like a wrong translation/unusual word used. in germany the water trap is called "Siphon"

Comment: Yes, "water trap" is the word I didn't know

Comment: Interesting idea, if I add a contact switch to determine whether the seat is up or down.